# How to hide an IP using .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to make a `RewriteRule` for all the links of my webpage but I cannot make it to work. I want that all links that I press on my webpage will be like:

```
domain.es
domain.es/section1
domain.es/section2
domain.es/section3/subsection1
```

and so on.

If I go directly to `domain.es` on my browser it works without problems (I have also some rules to redirect that the index also will not being shown) but if I press on any link of my webpage the url is showing like: `1.1.1.1/section1`, I mean, it shows the url with the IP instead of the domain.

Further, if I also go directly to `domain.es/section1` on my browser I do not have any problem and any IP is shown on the url. The url is being shown correctly, using the domain instead the IP.

Here is the `.htaccess` file that I have by the moment:

```
IndexIgnore *

Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1\.1\.1\.1:8082/proyect
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.es/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I do not know if it can be the problem but I am using `Joomla`. Also notice that it is a fake IP, instead of 1.1.1.1 I have my real IP on my project.

Why if I use my urls directly on the browser they do not show the IP and if I press on a link of my webpage the IP is being shown? Is there a special rule to detect when you press on a link?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is likely not related to your rewriting at all. I’d rather suspect that Joomla outputs these absolute URLs - have you checked what the HTML code of those links actually contains?

Comment: @CBroe How can I check it? Or do you mean that should I check the href of the links?

Comment: View the page source code in your browser, or use the DOM inspector

Comment: @CBroe Oh, so you mean to inspect the href of that link on the page, right?

Comment: @CBroe Ok I have checked it and the links are like: `<span onclick="window.document.location.href=’/project/section1’">Section1</span>`

Comment: Apart from that that would only throw syntax errors (`’` is not the same as `'`), it would not cause the IP address to be used for the absolute URL. Check if maybe a `base` element exists in the header. And go check Joomla settings again, I think it is most likely due to one of the basic settings.

Comment: @CBroe The simple quotes are like this because I have copied it on a email and copied it to this comment from there but they are correct on the webpage. I will look at configuration and reply you if I get something :)

Answer (score 0):

CBroe is right that showing IP address is due to some code/config issue not related with shown `mod_rewrite` rules.

However your last rule to redirect IP to hostname is incorrect because `HTTP_HOST` only matches hostname without scheme, port, URI etc.

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1\.1\.1\.1$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =8082
RewriteRule ^proyect(/.*)?$ http://domain.es%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC,NE]

# remaining Joomla rules

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule ^ index.php [F]

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !^index\.php$ index.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: It seems not to work. I think that it is something related with Joomla because the links are like: `<span onclick="window.document.location.href=’/project/section1’">‌​Section1</span>`

Comment: You should place this rule before all other rules. Aisi what is the URL being received by web server?